# Why does `Object.keys/values/entries` return Arrays while `Array...` return iterators

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In ES6/ES2018+,

- `Object.keys(), Object.values(), Object.entries()` seem to return concrete array types.
- `Array.keys(), Array.values(), Array.entries()` seem to return iterators.

Is the reason for the disparity between these APIs?

Comment: Probably to be consistent with the versions of those APIs on `Object.prototype`

Comment: I'm struggling to think of any reason why the two would return the same thing. In particular if `Array.values()` returns an *array*, then...that's going to be the same as the input array, so `Array.values(arr)` is the same as `arr.slice()`. The other two are going to be the same as `Object.keys` and `Object.entries` which already exist, so having the same functionality would be redundant.

Comment: I also suspect that `Object.values` and `Object.entries` don't give you an iterator because `Object.keys` existed in ES5 and returns an array. So, the two compliment that method and are consistent with it, while `Array.keys` is completely new and can use newer features *and* doesn't need to repeat the existing functionality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a matter of time. `Object.keys` was introduced with ES5, iterables were introduced with ES6. However, iterators do make more sense for all of them. Thus `Object.values` and `Object.entries` probably follow `Object.keys` for consistency, and the array methods use the new iterator interface.